# Is it possible to screen share (VNC?) into another instance of a user account?

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm trying to remotely log into my home MBP that has 4 monitors, and that's proving to be a pain when connecting from a screen with one monitor. I just view one screen at a time, but often when I make new windows or something, it opens on a different monitor out of sight. What would be ideal is if I could just log in as another instance of my user account that doesn't actually show up with what the computer is showing, but all windows would show up on one screen as if no external monitors were plugged into the MBP. Does what I'm looking for make sense and is something like that possible?

Comment: VNC is horrible - always has been.  Try something like TeamViewer or depending on what you need to do, you might find the Bash/Zsh shell (Terminal) quicker and easier.

Comment: @Allan Do you mean from a security pov or something else...? I think since vnc/rfb with ard is built in for Mac it's unavoidable that people use it. Or do you mean the realvnc software?

Comment: I’m speaking from a performance and  feature set standpoint.  It’s nowhere near what RDP can do.  VNC (RealVNC included) sends the entire screen with every update, thus the lag.  Add extra displays and the VNC client on the remote can’t differentiate monitors because  it’s sending the *entire* extended display.  There are 3rd party solutions like TeamViewer that work fairly well.  But, if you don’t absolutely need a GUI, a shell is as fast as can be.

Comment: @Allan I mean like I said vnc is what is built in and what ard uses so if you need fleet management then team viewer isn't going to cut it. Not to mention I don't know of any third party solutions that can do what the OP wants to do (not that vnc can do it but it can do something close). unfortunately it seems likely GUI is absolutely necessary since he has multiple displays connected and he often makes new windows or something and has to look around for them.

Comment: @kumowoon1025 TeamViewer is free for personal use.

Comment: @Allan I never said otherwise...unless you're just trying to promote TeamViewer? I'm not sure why you would though since it doesn't do what OP wants anyways

Answer (score -1):

No something like that isn't possible, only one gui login session for each user id. If you had multiple accounts set up then yes it might be possible but I have a feeling that isn't going to help much, if that won't be an issue then just log in using the alternate account and it'll open a new gui login.

Some things you might want to try (I'm assuming you're using a Mac on both ends and either ARD or Screen Sharing to remotely connect.)

You could view all four screens at the same time by turning scaling on (this wouldn't be very useful unless you were remoting in from a machine with a huuuuge display, or you could only turn scaling on when you want to view all screens to find that window you just opened)

You could also control-click on the app icon in the dock, go to options, then assign the app to a desktop on a particular display so it opens new windows and you know which display it's gonna be on.

But yeah, no what you're looking for isn't possible in macOS, I'm not confident but I don't know any other window systems that let you log in into separate gui sessions with one user id, so it might not make too much sense either.

Edit: alternative workaround

Okay another workaround which I feel is pretty messy is to create another user account and physically log in using that one.

No need to log out of the original account (that you said had things running and didn't want to log out of). You just need the account that is logged in locally to be the alternate account.

You can either do this by directly switching accounts on the local machine, or you can log into the main account using screen sharing, and then use the user switching menu to log into the alternate account. (This doesn't log you out of the first account)

Then disconnect (close screen sharing) if you switched accounts remotely.

Now, since the local machine is logged into the alternate account, if you try to remote into the machine and log in using your original account, it'll tell you that there's a session already and if you'd like to share the screen or log in as yourself. Logging in as yourself give you another gui login, under a separate user of course.

But at this point the screen share will probably replicate the local machine's display setup. If you want everything to show up in one virtual remote display, open system preferences, display settings, and mirror all displays except the main one (maybe built in one?).

This doesn't mess with the display configuration when you're logged in locally, only when you're using vnc to remote in. (Not completely sure how, it creates virtual display projector devices that sort of replicate the hardware computer is connected to, but it's not the actual display so the settings are separate. On the flip side, the settings are preserved if you use the same method to remote in again)

This is a super messy workaround but I hope it sort of answers the additional question you asked in comment.

Comment: When you say only one guy login session for each user id... that just made me wonder... if I logged out (which I actually probably won't do because I have things running, but just theoretically)... if I logged out, might I then be able to log in remotely and have all content show up in one window?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed Well it doesn't matter if you log out, you can stay logged in, the important thing is the local machine gui is logged into a different user account. Super messy workaround so I'll add to answer.

Comment: I just tried it - even with my home MBP logged into a second user account, when I Screen share to it and log in as my main account, it still shows the four monitors through screen sharing.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed Yes, that is the expected result, did you do the steps where I said to go to display settings and have all other displays other than your "main" one that you want to use configured to mirror the main display? If the explanation of the settings you need to make this work wasn't good enough I apologize but I'll do my best to get this working for you.